# Rank of an affine map

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Take the affine transformation
$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
2 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
3 & 2 & 4 & 5
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}X_{1}\\
X_{2}\\
X_{3}\\
X_{4}
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}2\\
-3\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$

I'm under the impression that this affine map is not surjective:

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
2 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
3 & 2 & 4 & 5
\end{pmatrix}$

Ignore the 'affineness' of the map as this is just an offset from
the origin.

We just need to check if we can construct every single point in space
within $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ as a linear combination of the columns of

$A$.

Let $\Phi_{A}:x\to Ax$.

We just need to find $rank(\Phi_{A})=dim(Im(\Phi_{A}))$

Let us find this by transforming $A$ into $RREF$ form. If we have
$3$ or more pivots, then we can conclude that the

transformation spans over three dimensional space.

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
2 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
3 & 2 & 4 & 5
\end{pmatrix}\overset{\rho_{2}\to\rho_{2}-2\rho_{1}}{\to}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
0 & -4 & -5 & -7\\
3 & 2 & 4 & 5
\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
0 & -4 & -5 & -7\\
3 & 2 & 4 & 5
\end{pmatrix}\overset{\rho_{3}\to\rho_{3}-3\rho_{1}}{\to}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
0 & -4 & -5 & -7\\
0 & -4 & -5 & -7
\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
0 & -4 & -5 & -7\\
0 & -4 & -5 & -7
\end{pmatrix}\overset{\rho_{3}\to\rho_{3}-\rho_{2}}{\to}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
0 & -4 & -5 & -7\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

We can finally see that we only have $2$ pivots, meaning that $rank(\Phi_{A})=dim(Im(\Phi_{A}))=2$
dimensional space; our map is

not surjective since $Im(\Phi_{A})=\mathbb{R}^{2}\neq\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, the last row of $A$ is the sum of the two first rows. Hence the rank is $2$ and neither the linear map given by $A$ nor the affine map $x\mapsto Ax+b$ can be surjective.

Comment: And this map would not be injective either because the matrix is not square right?

Comment: Not being square would not be sufficient, but this matrix has more columns than rows, which is sufficient for not being injective!